# Возникает ошибка при повторном оправлении запроса. Без rabbitmq всё работает

Tags: node.js, express, rabbitmq

Учусь программированию на nodejs, сейчас работаю над одним заданием, но возникает ошибка.

Работаю над заданием не один, поэтому сам себе в очередь "Response" отправляю ответ.
Суть приложения проста. Приходит запрос я достаю из него тело, метод, ссылку и т.д. И отправляю это в очередь. Дальше над этими данными работает другой код, который обрабатывает их, производит работы с бд и отправляет мне ответ, который я отправляю.

При первом запросе(через postman) все работает хорошо, ответ приходит, но когда повторно отправляю запрос появляется ошибка:Error [541]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. При этом ошибка не появляется, если убрать код с rabbitmq из Router.js.
Использую node js, express, rabbitmq.

Gateway.js

```
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api')
const express = require('express')

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function (error0,connection){
    if(error0){
        throw error0
    }
    connection.createChannel(function (error1,channel){
        if(error1){
            throw error1
        }
        channel.assertQueue('Request',{durable: false})
        channel.assertQueue('Response',{durable: false})

        const app = express()
        const router = require('./Router.js')
        app.use('/api/', router)

        app.use(express.json())
        app.listen(5293,()=>{console.log("Server started")})
    })
})
```

Router.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const router = express.Router()
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api')

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function (error0,connection){
    if(error0){
        throw error0
    }
    connection.createChannel(function (error1,channel){
        if(error1){
            throw error1
        }
        channel.assertQueue('Request',{durable: false})
        channel.assertQueue('Response',{durable: false})

        router.get('/main/:id', function(req,res){
            const fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl
            const method = req.method
            const fullReq = JSON.stringify({"Method": method, "URL":fullUrl, "Body": req.body, "ID":req.params.id })
            channel.sendToQueue('Request',Buffer.from(fullReq))
            channel.sendToQueue('Response', Buffer.from('{"ID":22,"dsd":"ds"}'))
            channel.consume('Response', function(msg){
                if(msg){                       
                    if(msg.content.toString()){
                        const message = msg.content.toString()
                        return res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(message))  
                    }    
                    else{
                        return res.status(404).json("")
                    }  
                }           
            },{noAck:true})

        })
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

Прошу помочь с решение данной проблемы. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался с данной ошибкой, причина которой была в неоднократной отправке ответа, т.е. несколько методов send() срабатывало на один запрос.
Попробуйте посмотреть через debugger, ход выполнения кода.